# Is there a weight distribution problem putting a FE lens on a Sony a6000?

Tags: sony, lens-mount, weight

**Context**

I am considering upgrading to Full Frame at some point for the Sony line and while I already have APS-C primes, I'm considering getting my first FE prime for my Sony α6000. I usually bring my camera with me on a shoulder strap.

**Question**

Given how small and lightweight the camera body, is there any weight problems on the mount/system if I walk around shooting with the α6000 with a larger lens like the 85mm/1.8 or even 70-200/4? Do these problems exist after I upgrade to say an a7rII or larger body?

**Update**

I usually walk around with my camera gear (camera on strap and ready to go) all day taking shots. What I'm more afraid of is if I have a 70-200/4 or some other lens on it that the weight might either damage the lens mount or lens itself. I know that for larger lens there is a tripod mount on the lens. By having the strap mounted to the camera, will that, long term damage my camera or lens?

**Not Related**

- [Should I buy an L Lens for my crop camera before buying a full-frame body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24690/should-i-buy-an-l-lens-for-my-crop-camera-before-buying-a-full-frame-body)
- [Will there be any difference in photos taken using full frame and crop lenses on a crop camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/will-there-be-any-difference-in-photos-taken-using-full-frame-and-crop-lenses-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no answer I'll post my "answer" here

As stated by other posts, it shouldn't really matter and really the torque matters than the direct weight, as a longer lens of the same weight has more effect on the lens. If a lens does not have a collar it should not matter at all.

That being said, when walking a shorter lens is easier to maneuver with if you're not holding it. With longer lens, it may just better to mount the shoulder strap tripod on the lens anyway. It will be awkward but **is** a valid solution there.

The mount, at least for Sony, is the same with FE and E bodies so it doesn't matter. A bigger body, has more weight to counteract a larger lens but as Sony lens scale up with size, it shouldn't matter for Sony systems. I can't comment on non-Sony body/lens.

TL;DR Shouldn't matter and you usually have bigger problems to deal with.