# Will Tamron 70-300mm f/4-5.6 Di VC USD work with Canon t3i?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, canon-600d, tamron

I wonder if this lenses will work with Canon T3i. The compatibility match on Amazon.com says they may not work but I know very little about the subject.

Comment: Assuming the lens has a Canon EF mount, yes it will. If you plan on using this lens below 150mm or so for the most part the Tamron is probably the best value for this class of lens. If you plan on using it mostly above 150mm, the Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 will outperform it at a lower price.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get it with a **Canon EF mount**, then yes.

(or EF-S, but as far as I know only Canon actually make EF-S lenses; even the 3rd-party lenses designed for crop sensors usually still have an EF mount).

Answer (score 0):

We have an existing question that already answers this. Take a look at:

[What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

The above will tell you that the "Di" in the product name indicates that it works with full frame cameras.

Further, we have questions that address full frame vs crop sensor(APS-C in this case) sensors, such as:

- [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)
- [Is it a wise-decision to buy full-frame lenses for use on an APS-C body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/is-it-a-wise-decision-to-buy-full-frame-lenses-for-use-on-an-aps-c-body)
- [When do the differences between APS-C and full frame sensors matter, and why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/when-do-the-differences-between-aps-c-and-full-frame-sensors-matter-and-why)

To sum it up, your camera is an APS-C Crop Sensor Camera. It will work with both full frame(EF) and crop sensor(EF-S) lenses. Tamron refers to full frame lenses as Di, thus it will work with both full frame and crop sensor cameras. The lens will certainly work with your camera.

Answer (score -4):

If you get this lens with the Canon mount, it will fit, even though Amazon says it may not work. The reason for the "incompatibility" is that Di lenses produce an image to fit a 35mm film frame or a full frame digital sensor. Using it with an APS-C sensor causes distortion and cropping.

Comment: I voted this answer down because I do not agree that using a full frame compatible lens on an APS-C sensor causes distortion. On the contrary, it uses the center of the frame which is typically of higher quality with less distortion or vignetting.