# Crop Sensor Enhances Zoom?

Tags: cropped-sensor, crop-factor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between focal length and crop factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-the-difference-between-focal-length-and-crop-factor)
>   [Does my crop sensor camera actually turn my lenses into a longer focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length)

I keep reading about how crop-sensors enhance the zoom of an image.

Example: `A 50mm lens is effectively a 70mm lens.`

What causes this to happen and how do you get the ratio to know what your lens is? In other words, How do you get 50mm=70mm?

Comment: Also relevant: [Does my crop sensor camera actually turn my lenses into a longer focal length?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crop sensors are smaller than full frame sensor. [The full frame sensor size came from the old days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/135_film) and has been used as a standard for digital sensors size.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_factor)

> *Crop factor is related to the ratio of the dimensions of a camera's imaging area compared to a reference format; most often, this term is applied to digital cameras, relative to 35 mm film format as a reference. In the case of digital cameras, the imaging device would be a digital sensor. The most commonly used definition of crop factor is the ratio of a 35 mm frame's diagonal (43.3 mm) to the diagonal of the image sensor in question; that is, CF=diag35mm / diagsensor. Given the same 3:2 aspect ratio as 35mm's 36mm x 24mm area, this is equivalent to the ratio of heights or ratio of widths; the ratio of sensor areas is the square of the crop factor.*

So to determine your crop factor, you need to know your DSLR sensor size. *It's 1.5 for Nikon, 1.6 for Canon, 2.0 for Olympus, 1.5 for Pentax and 1.5 for Sony.*

To calculate the *effective focal length* or the ***focal length multiplier***, use this formula:

***focal length multiplier*** = ***focal length x crop factor***.

For example, let's say that your crop factor is 1.5 and your lens's focal length is 50mm, then the focal length multiplier = 1.5 x 50 = 75mm.

[Bear this in mind: the physical focal length of your lens didn't change at all.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/does-my-crop-sensor-camera-actually-turn-my-lenses-into-a-longer-focal-length) What you see in your photo is the effect of your crop sensor, let me explain more:

Look at the image below, the red rectangle is for the full frame sensors, now if you are using a lens on a full frame camera and used 50mm lens to get this picture below, the photo will be everything inside the red rectangle. If you replaced your lens with a 75mm lens you will get a photo with everything inside the blue rectangle. Which is the same if you mount your 50mm lens on a cropped sensor camera with crop factor = 1.5

Crop Factor doesn't enhance the zoom, it just gives you the field of view that you would see if you zoomed more.

The image below is from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_factor) Wikipedia article.

[image: crop-factor]