# Difference in image capture area between full frame and medium frame

Tags: full-frame, field-of-view, crop-factor

Is the view/capture area of image from any camera with same lens (say 50mm) change when going from a full frame to a medium frame type camera?

Comment: You can also check out [this question and answer/s.](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29313/does-crop-factor-still-apply-to-a-vintage-film-slr-lens)

Comment: To confirm. If I placed 1 to 10 markers with 5 being centre using a 50mm lens. On full frame I could see marker 3 to 7, then I did exactly same with a medium frame sensor, I should be able to see more, say marker 2 to 8?

Comment: More like marker 1 to 9 or 0 to 10 depending on the exact size of the medium format being used.

Comment: Yes, you will be able to see more ***IF*** you're using the same subject distance and the same focal length. However, if you're going to try to achieve the same field of view, you'll need to change focal length or subject distance (or both). If you do this, you get get different background compression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The larger the format, the wider the view.

The Pentax 645D, for example, has approximately a 0.78x crop factor. So a 50mm lens on a 645D would give a field of view similar to a 39mm lens--assuming the 50mm lens's image circle can cover the entire sensor of the 645D.