# What's the magnification of a full frame macro lens on a MFT camera?

Tags: macro, micro-four-thirds, full-frame, magnification

I think I've got this right but I would like to be positive before I buy a lens.

If I were to use a Nikkor 55mm full frame macro lens with a 1:2 magnification and a 9inch min focus on a micro four thirds body it would still have a 9inch min focus but because of the crop factor, the magnification would be 1:1. Correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a camera's crop factor apply to the magnification of macro shots?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8932/does-a-cameras-crop-factor-apply-to-the-magnification-of-macro-shots)

Answer (score 9):

Sorry, no; the magnification designation of a macro lens is the ratio of the physical size of the object to the size it appears on the sensor, meaning at 1:2 magnification, the image of the object would be half life size on the sensor (so e.g. a 2cm diameter coin would have an image 1cm wide on the sensor).

Of course being a smaller sensor, the image *would* take up a greater proportion of the sensor than would be the case with a full frame camera, so would appear larger on an image printed at the same dimensions, but this difference in magnification occurs when the print is made, not when the image is exposed.

You are correct that the 9 inch minimum focus would be unchanged, however.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. Thanks for the clarification.